# Formula error in loop estimating log linear model

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to estimate several log linear model in a model selection procedure. In the selection procedure I first add the main effects and than in each step the corresponding order of interaction effects. To simplify things I wanted to write a loop, which estimates the log linear model and saves each in a list

```
fits <- list()
for (i in (1:3)) {  
    if (i < 2) {
        fits <- loglm(Freq ~ ., data = table.analysis.b)
    } else {
        fits[i] <- loglm(Freq ~ . + . ^ i, data = table.analysis.b)
    }
}
```

The loop breaks with the corresponding error:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid power in
>   formula

The data structure looks similar to this:

```
trstplt stfgov                          educ     gndr  vote   Freq
    40       5      3 Upper secondary education  Male  Yes  0.0001
    41       1      4 Upper secondary education  Male  Yes  2.0000
    42       2      4 Upper secondary education  Male  Yes  6.0000
    43       3      4 Upper secondary education  Male  Yes 32.0000
    44       4      4 Upper secondary education  Male  Yes 17.0000
    45       5      4 Upper secondary education  Male  Yes  0.0001
```

**Update:** 
I have found a solution based on the example here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/looping_strings.htm

```
    varlist<-c(2,3)
models<-lapply(varlist, function(x){ 
  if (x>1) {  loglm(substitute(Freq ~ .^i, list(i = x)), data = table.analysis.b)
  } else{ 
loglm(Freq~., data=table.analysis.b)
}})
```

Comment: Not positive, but I don't think you can do this: `. ^ i`

Comment: It seems ambiguous. Do you want `(everything)^i` or each element within `.` to the i?

Comment: Also, its not advised to include i-th degree terms without all the i-1, i-2, ... i-n-1-th degree terms as well. You risk missing the zeros of the lower order terms.

Comment: I figured out that indeed .^i within the loop doesn't work.  Interactively I can estimate e.g. loglm(Freq ~ . ^2, data = table.analysis.b) and it includes the first order terms and the second order terms, as I would wish to do.